WPF Rounded Window Contents issue
I have a custom window design which I use. It has rounded corners which can cause issues when I add other controls into the window.
Window style definition:
<Style x:Key="Authentication_Window" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

  <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AppPrimaryBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
  <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Topmost" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
  <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />

  <Setter Property="Template">

    <Setter.Value>

      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

        <Grid>

          <Border Background="White"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  BorderThickness="3"
                  CornerRadius="8">

            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="8"
                    Style="{DynamicResource ShadowedBorder_Base}" />

          </Border>

        </Grid>

      </ControlTemplate>

    </Setter.Value>

  </Setter>

</Style>

The issue I have is that I have created custom Header/FooterControl (inheriting from ContentControl) which I want to add to this window. These controls is also used in other windows (which do not have rounded corners, or have different CornerRadius).
My question is, is there a way to have the Header/Footer Control automatically work out what radius the corners need to be based on the window it is placed inside of?
(For HeaderControl I would only want to change the top corners, and for the FooterControl I would only want to change the bottom corners)
TIA.

is there a way to have the Header/Footer Control automatically work out what radius the corners need to be based on the window it is placed inside of? It is certainly possible to get a reference to the parent window if that's what you are asking...

I think a converter would be a reasonable way to go, you could pass itself into the converter, check if its HeaderControl or FooterControl return a Thickness with appropriate values which will become the margin.
In the example below I've used VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() to find the controls parent but this would fail if you have your control nested within additional controls so you need to get to the correct level to find if its the Header/Footer, perhaps by passing in the correct control.
Also according to this: Can a WPF converter access the control to which it is bound? if you want to pass in itself you need to use IMultiValueConverter and use <MultiBinding> in XMAL.
Note: I wrote this very quickly just to see what I could get into the converter so all error handling, etc, have been omitted.
public class ControlTypeToMarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((FrameworkElement)values[0]);

        if (parentObject != null)
        {
            if (parentObject is HeaderControl)
            {
                return new Thickness(5, 5, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

